# E: footer is wrong E: Signature verification failed E: error 21 Installation aborted - Trying to apply update from SD Card in my locked phone

Tags: android, mode, recovery, locked

everyone. I've been stuck in this problem when I wanted to apply update from a sd card in my phone, all of this in Recovery Mode. I'm doing this because my phone is locked and I want to unlock it without losing data. Thanks in advance.

This is what I did:

1.I accessed to recovery mode and then I moved to "Apply update from sd card"

2.I selected the .zip named aromafm-1.91.zip (even after the first tried I thougth perhaps with another version it could work, but it's the same with all of them)

3.And finally after that, the phone throws this error